# xxx.azurewebsites.net is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: microservices, azure-web-app-service

Getting 500 error post deploying microservices on app service on the Azure

[image]

Comment: What kind of application is this? Does it depend on a backend? Is it itself a backend application? Is it a front end application? 500 Internal Server Errors have to do with databases. Maybe you forgot to remove some local connection string before deploying.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this same error today, for me the source of the problem occurred during startup. My application was trying to create a file, and this is not allowed.

"Running from package makes wwwroot read-only, so you will receive an error when writing files to this directory."

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package

Answer (score 0):

Generally 500 comes due to application error on the server.

When "Server Error in '/' Application" comes , did you observe anything in "Diagnose and Solve Problem" under 5xx errors.

[image]

[image]

3) You can enable FREB logs . Follow this blog how to do it https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/01/27/enable-failed-reuqest-tracing-for-an-azure-app-service-web-app/

4) See Events Logs in Kudu https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/videos/what-is-kudu-with-david-ebbo/

Comment: Resolved by adding AzureServiceBus to appsettings.json